# why is the suffix of alcohols -ol but not -al?

Tags: etymology

According to the IUPAC nomenclature, we put the suffix “-ol” to alcohols while we put the suffix “-al” to aldehydes.

This will be related to some etymology issues. I presume “-ol” and “-al” are derived from the ending of “alcohol” and the beginning of “aldehyde” respectively.

I get very confused about this. Both “alcohols” and “aldehydes”, I mean the English words, start with “al”. Then, why alcohols cannot have the “al” suffix?

Comment: If alkanols R-OH became alkanals, what would happen with alkanals R-CHO ? // By other words,generally, if having two different groups suggests having the same name, only one can keep it. The other must have assigned some other name.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Chemical nomenclature did not emerge systematically. Some names have been borrowed from other languages centuries ago including German, French and Arabic. Alcohol is derived from Arabic, from the the time of Middle Ages. The word al-kali (alkali) are remnants of those times. There is no way current nomenclature can be changed.

From the Elsevier Dictionary of Chemetymology- The Whies and Whences of Chemical Nomenclature and Terminology, we can see:

> **Alcohol** derived from al-kuhul (Arabic: powder) referring to the
> alchemistic procedure of reducing samples, through several
> purification steps, to a powder, the supposedly pure essence of the
> substance in question; thus alcohol is the essence (or spirit) of
> wine; the same word, spelled kohl, is used for powdered antimony as a
> cosmetic preparation

Aldehyde is rather recent

> **Aldehyde** coined by contraction of *alcohol dehydrogenatus* (New Latin: aldehyde  literally dehydrogenated alcohol)

Hope that solves the mystery behind -ol and -al. There is a need to distinguish -ol and -al groups and most chemists have accepted this name to represent an alcohol and an aldehyde, at least in the English language.

There will be certain molecules when both functional groups are present and the suffixes will be determined by IUPAC's priority list.

Comment: To complement the answer: Wikipedia equally has sections about etymology regarding the names e.g., of [alcohols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcohol_(chemistry)#Etymology), and [aldehydes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aldehyde#Etymology), the later including a footnote to Liebig's definition in a publication in 1835.